# How to ignore mouse event triggered by sibling inside of the trigger (image area)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, mouse

Ok, lt me explain to you this very strange problem on which I am working the second week right now without any solution.

Imagine I have an image 100x100px. 
Around the whole image I have an image area 100x100 (let us  call the image area ALPHA). 
I have also second Image Area on the image, but this time not around the whole image, but just inside of it (10x10) in the middle of the image (let's call the second Image area BETA).

That Means that image area BETA is inside of the image area ALPHA.

Now, I want to add a border to the image when I am with the mouse over my image area ALPHA and to remove the border when I am mouse out of the image area ALPHA with following code (via jQuery) :

```
$("area.ALPHA").hover(
  function () {
    $('img').css('border','1px solid #000');
  }, 
  function () {
    $('img').css('border','none');
  }
);
```

This code is working very well.

But I want also that when I am hovering over my second image area BETA that the code above will be executed. But it is not working.

I know why it is not working, because when I am with the mouse over my image area BETA, I am also with the mouse out of the image area ALPHA.

I was trying to solve this freakin problem, but unfortunately I realised I am not able to solve this problem on my own, so please help me. Is there any possibility to do something like this for example ?:

```
if ($("area#ALPHA").mouseout === false && $("area#BETA").mouseenter === true) {
   // ignore the first event (or something like this)...
}
```

My first thought was event.stopPropagation(), but it is not working. Maybe I've just used it the wrong way....

PS: I know I could do this same just with CSS or without the image area. But I have to do it this way...

If you dont understand my explanation, I am ready to explain it one more time more exactly.

Comment: Please put your sample html+js code in a site like jsfiddle.net so that it makes it easier for others to understand/respond to your question.

Comment: It's easier to *show* what you're doing than it is to *describe*. Give us the code. And, then, [show us the code](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: _I know why it is not working, because when I am with the mouse over my image area BETA, I am also with the mouse out of the image area ALPHA._  When you hover your BETA you are actually still inside ALPHA. In my example given below (i hope div and img behavior is the same) you have to attach the same event when you hover your BETA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my interpretation of your requirements [example](http://jsfiddle.net/nEdQ8/3/)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#ALPHA, #BETA").hover(
        function () {
          $(this).css('border','1px solid #000');
        }, 
        function () {
          $(this).css('border','none');
        }
     );
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You might do better to use CSS instead:

```
area#ALPHA {
    border:none;
}

area#ALPHA:hover {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

This will add a border when the mouse is in alpha, but will regard the mouse as not being in ALPHA whilst it is in BETA.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your image modification code outside event, ie. another function.
Bind hover handler, and call outside event function of alpha, and vice versa.

Let me shut up, and code talk:

```
function insideAlpha(){
    $('.result').text("inside alpha");
}

function outsideAlpha(){
    $('.result').text("outside alpha");
}


$(function(){
    $("div.alpha").hover(
      function () {
          insideAlpha();
      }, 
      function () {
          outsideAlpha();
      }
    );
    $("div.beta").hover(
        function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            outsideAlpha();
        },
        function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            insideAlpha();
        }
     );
});​
```

Here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fBKUw/):

Comment: thx for your fiddle. But when I am in the small div, it shows me the text "outside alpha", but I want that it will show me "inside alpha".

Comment: well, it normally shows "inside alpha", if you omit the beta hover codes.

Answer (score 0):

This works too, http://jsfiddle.net/uurBc/

```
   $(".hover").mouseenter(function(e){
       result = $(this).attr('id')
       $(".result").html(result)
       e.stopPropagation();
     })

   $(".hover").mouseleave(function(e){
       $(".result").html("")
       $(this).parents(".hover").trigger('mouseenter')
       e.stopPropagation();
   })​
```

The trick was to trigger manually trigger the mouseenter event for a parent (alpha) when you leave the child (beta).

Comment: Looking back at your question, I'm actually not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do. Can you post some example HTML?